# Why we get this error in hibernate usually org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 17002...

Tags: hibernate

I am getting following Error

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 17002
```

Getting above error pointing to statement

```
Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
```

Comment: Looks like a Connection error, some more details like which database you are using and a more complete stack trace would definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Oracle, the full error description is :

> Oracle Error 17002 “Io Exception: The Network Adapter could not
>   establish the connection”

It means that your DB is offline or you have a bad config.

But sometimes it is because you use the wrong jars which are incompatible with your DB version. You should check the latest version on the official website.